# i stuck in leetcode problem 151. Reverse Words in a String

Tags: java, string, stream, time-complexity, reverse

Given an input string s, reverse the order of the words.
A word is defined as a sequence of non-space characters. The words in s will be separated by at least one space.
Return a string of the words in reverse order concatenated by a single space.

```java
class Solution {

public:

    string reverseWords(string s) {
        string ans;
        int i =0;
        int n = s.size();
        while(i<n)
        {
            while(i<n and s[i]==' ')
                i++;
            if(i>=n)
                break;
            int j =i+1;
            while(j<n and s[j]!=' ')
                j++;
            string word = s.substr(i,j-1);
            if(ans.size()==0)
                ans = word;
            else
                ans = word + " "+ ans;
            i = j+1;
            
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Expected output-"blue is sky the"
my output-"blue is blue sky is th"

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: FYI: The solution can be written in 4 or so lines using `std::istringstream`, and `std::stack<std::string>`.  There is no need to check for spaces.  As a matter of fact, maybe that's what the question is looking for in terms of an answer, i.e. usage of a stack data structure.

Comment: Also, I won't post this as an answer, since it doesn't look anything like your attempt (which to me is very convoluted, given the actual simplicity of the solution if using the proper data structures), but [this is an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9704c28f6900e98).  Now, to figure out your code requires you to debug the code, and then posting your results of your debugging in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one small typo in your code.

The line

```
        string word = s.substr(i,j-1);
```

should be

```
std::string word = s.substr(i, j - i);
```

So you mixed up i with 1.

No big deal.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string reverseWords(std::string s) {
    std::string ans;
    int i = 0;
    int n = s.size();
    while (i < n)
    {
        while (i < n and s[i] == ' ')
            i++;
        if (i >= n)
            break;
        int j = i + 1;
        while (j < n and s[j] != ' ')
            j++;
        std::string word = s.substr(i, j - i);
        if (ans.size() == 0)
            ans = word;
        else
            ans = word + " " + ans;
        i = j + 1;

    }
    return ans;
}
int main() {
    std::cout << reverseWords("ab cd ef");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

java script solution:

```js
return str.split(' ').filter(s=>s!==' ').reverse().join(' ')
```

Comment: Question calls for O(1) space though